# Why does installing GIMP over MacPorts download more than just GIMP?

Tags: macos, port, gimp

I freshly installed Mac OS X Lion yesterday and today I wanted to try MacPorts and install GIMP with it, because the Gimp homepage says it's easy installed with MacPorts, so I tried the command

```
sudo port install gimp
```

and now it installs a lot of stuff, that doesn't belong to gimp (in my opinion).

It has already installed and downloaded boost libraries, cmake, a lot of gnome packages and lot of small packages. It's working for some hours now and I think that's strange.

I have some experience with the terminal, experience with C and building and I think building these packages takes very long and shouldn't be necessary for gimp...

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: `that doesn't belong to gimp (in my opinion).` <-- That is where you were mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal and yes, GIMP does need a lot of stuff (and these libraries/tool often in turn need a lot of other libraries/tools). It's not unusual if MacPorts would download and install a few dozen packages in the process and can take up to a few hours (depending on machine and the number of packages). Sit back and read a good book.

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts installes every dependency seperately somewhere, instead of using libraries inherent in your system. So wait until all dependencies are installed...